# how to access the content of the "Comments" column from the fiddler script?

Tags: fiddler

It is possible to comment a session by associating it a text in fiddler. The comment is shown in the "Comments" column. Is there a way to get access to this text from the fiddler script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments column can be accessed via the session flag named `ui-comments`.

Adding this in OnBeforeResponse method of the script would append the Time To Last Byte to any other comments:
`oSession["ui-comments"] = oSession["ui-comments"] + oSession.oResponse.iTTLB;`

Note that you could also add a completely new column using BindUIColumn by placing the following method in the script file.

```
public static BindUIColumn("Response Time", 100)
    function ResponseTime(os: Session)
    {
        return os.oResponse.iTTLB + "ms";
    }
```

Comment: thanks! is there a reference documentation of the fiddler script api? i am often finding myself guessing how to do things from the cookbook samples...